# ERROR Could not load RNOneSignal native module. Make sure native dependencies are properly linked

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I am trying to implement One Signal on my Expo application without ejecting my application.
I followed all the steps in the document but I get an error.
`Could not load RNOneSignal native module. Make sure native dependencies are properly linked.`
After a little search, I found out that many users encountered such a problem and could not implement One Signal on their Expo application.
Is it possible to help me quickly to solve my problem?

I tried different versions of `onesignal-expo-plugin` and `react-native-onesignal` but it doesn't work.
please help.